Android Canvas.drawPoint method draws nothing
I'm doing some work with Canvas.drawPoint(float, float, Paint), but I found a strange thing: this method doesn't work.
At first, I thought it was a problem with my code, so I wrote a simple test code:

public class TestView extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(200, 200, 300, 300, paint);   //works well

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for(int x = 300; x <= 400; x++)
            for(int y = 300; y <= 400; y++)
                canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);        //not work
    }
}


This code should be able to draw two rectangles(black one draw by drawRect, green one draw by drawPoint), but the result shows only black rectangle:

I tested this on simulator API 35, why the drawPoint don't work, is this a bug of Android 12+ ?

Starting with API level 31, the default Paint constructor turns on anti-aliasing by default. This change is noted in the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#Paint(). Anti-aliasing a single pixel basically washes it out completely, so it'll look like the draw failed. If you call setAntiAlias(false) on your paint, it should fix it: https://i.sstatic.net/JpMHPzU2.png.

@MikeM. thanks for you comment. your comment is the perfect answer, I tried and it works great. please post it as answer, and I will accept.

Ah, good! I'm too lazy to post answers anymore, though, so please feel free to finish this up however you like. Thank you for the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!
